# Unable to cancel a Servicestack Facebook authentication proccess

Tags: api, servicestack, facebook-login

When accessing "/api/auth/facebook" i'm redirected to facebook ouath dialog, but when trying to cancel, i keep getting redirected to the same facebook ouath dialog.

This means i cannot cancel this process. 
Is this a bug?

Comment: Maybe look into some Web.config appSettings? Some examples from  SocialBootStrapApi https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/Web.config#L37

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue a little while back.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/850